# how to loop files in folder and rename extension in sftp

Tags: sftp, rename

Could someone show me how to rename all files extension inside folder in sftp?

Example, I have folder "Test" in sftp and inside this folder have few files, such as, `test1.tmp`, `test2.tmp`..... and I want to rename all files that have extension 'tmp' to .csv. so the result after rename should be like this. `test1.csv`, `test2.csv` ...... But in sftp not all bash command that can execute.

I tried like this already

```
find . -name "*.tmp" -exec rename 's/\.tmp$/.csv/' '{}' \;
```

but it say Invalid Command, seem command find no working in sftp.

Comment: Yes, `find` is a Unix command-line tool, not a file transfer command.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `rename` [SFTP command](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sftp&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%206.2-RELEASE&format=html) too. If you're using Windows and using WinSCP then you're lucky enough to use wildcards and simply run `rename *.tmp *.csv`.

```
c:\WinSCP>WinSCP.com
winscp> open sftp://bcs78@example.com:22/ -privatekey=bcs78.key.ppk
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Using username "bcs78".
Authenticating with public key "bcs78@laptop".
Authenticated.
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] bcs78@example.com
winscp> ls
-rw-rw-r--   1 bcs78    bcs78            2 Aug 30 12:23:34 2018 03.tmp
drwxr-xr-x  14 bcs78    bcs78         4096 Aug 30 12:21:49 2018 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 bcs78    bcs78            2 Aug 30 12:23:11 2018 01.tmp
drwxrwxr-x   2 bcs78    bcs78         4096 Aug 30 12:23:34 2018 .
-rw-rw-r--   1 bcs78    bcs78            2 Aug 30 12:23:23 2018 02.tmp
winscp> rename *.tmp *.csv
03.tmp
01.tmp
02.tmp
winscp> ls
-rw-rw-r--   1 bcs78    bcs78            2 Aug 30 12:23:23 2018 02.csv
drwxr-xr-x  14 bcs78    bcs78         4096 Aug 30 12:21:49 2018 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 bcs78    bcs78            2 Aug 30 12:23:34 2018 03.csv
drwxrwxr-x   2 bcs78    bcs78         4096 Aug 30 12:23:54 2018 .
-rw-rw-r--   1 bcs78    bcs78            2 Aug 30 12:23:11 2018 01.csv
winscp>
```

In Linux you likely need to script this since the Openssh or the Putty implementation does not support wildcards.

Comment: Your answer uses WinSCP. In WinSCP `rename` command indeed supports wildcards. But your link points to OpenSSH `sftp` `rename` command, which does not support wildcards in `rename` command. You should correct/clarify this.